# delayed response from chatterbot api python

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

when I started working on chatterbot API its result was coming frequently but gradually its response was getting delayed day by day. Now it's taking around 2 minutes to respond for a simple "hello" message. It's not a problem with the code. the problem is something else. Can anyone help me with this?

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
bot = ChatBot(
    'Norman',
    storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
    input_adapter='chatterbot.input.TerminalAdapter',
    output_adapter='chatterbot.output.TerminalAdapter',
    logic_adapters=[
        'chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation',
        'chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter'
    ],
    database='./db.sqlite3'
)
bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
bot.train([
    'How are you?',
    'I am good.',
    'That is good to hear.',
    'Thank you',
    'You are welcome.'
])

while True:
    try:
        your_input = input("You: ")
        bot_output = bot.get_response(your_input)
        print(bot_output)

    except(KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the code is using Terminal Input Adapater.

According to [docs](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/input/index.html) :

> ```
> The input terminal adapter allows a user to type into their terminal to communicate with the chat bot.
> ```

So it is basically used to get input from terminal.
 The code also tries to get manual user input using input() (inside while loop). This makes processing slower.
 By removing Terminal adapter as input adapter this problem can be solved.

Comment: its a compllete fresh program that i have written right now. Still facing the same issue

Comment: You have to remove the old db file if you are using a fresh code. I mean if it is a different bot.

Comment: Yes, Its a new db file that got created now only and is very small in size (32 kb)

Comment: still there is delay?

Comment: Yes, still delayed.

Comment: You are saying it happens with every bots you create or only this particular bot? try creating bots in different directories and check the speed.

Comment: I got the solution. it was happening bcz of `input_adapter='chatterbot.input.TerminalAdapter'`. after removing this it worked. I dont know why

Comment: Its weird. Are you sure this is the real issue?

Comment: One thing I noticed is you are using terminal adpater to get input from terminal and again using input() to get input from terminal which is obviously unnecessary. May be that is what making it runs slower

Comment: I corrected that one. i removed input and output adapter

Comment: Can I add this as a solution here?